# Absolutely positioned element is scrolled with content, why?

Tags: html, css

I have the [following setup:](https://jsfiddle.net/ta1ka7bv/) (try scrolling the content)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
  <div class="content">
    1<br>
    2<br>
    3<br>
    4<br>
    5<br>
    6<br>
    7<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

The problem is that backdrop for some reason is scrolled top with the content. Why is this happening? I was expecting the backdrop to remain still since it's positioned relative to the wrapper borders, not content's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrollable area is defined by the wrapper via its `overflow: auto` declaration. Since wrapper serves as the containing block for both the content and the backdrop (due to `position: relative`), this causes both elements to scroll together. In other words, this is due to *both* `overflow: auto` and `position: relative` on the same parent element, working in tandem.

Note that absolute positioning does not make an element immune to scrolling; when an absposed element does not appear to scroll, that is simply because its containing block does not scroll, and whatever is scrolling apart from the absposed element is some other element that is *not* its containing block. That is not the case in your setup. See the last example in [section 11.1.1 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) for another example of this.

Comment: thanks a lot, what would be the best fix here? adding another wrapper with `position:relative` and removing position relative from the current wrapper?

Comment: @Maximus: That would be the simplest if you can modify your HTML. However if your backdrop is meant to be an overlay (i.e. sit above the content), it will prevent the user from scrolling the content. This can be prevented with `.backdrop { pointer-events: none }` but pointer-events is not well supported by older browsers and solving that might be non-trivial.

Comment: @BoltClock `absposed` = absolutely positioned? I like it. Did you coin that? Well done.

Comment: @gibberish: Nope, it's actually a pretty common abbreviation!